# Do reduced relative clauses stack?

Tags: relative-clauses

I was wondering if you can always get (3-4) from (1-2) or if there is some kind of restriction on this sort of stacking

> (1) The door closed by the janitor
>
> (2) The door expected to be opened by the principal
>
> (3) The door closed by the janitor expected to be opened by the principal
>
> (4) The door expected to be opened by the principal (just recently) closed by the janitor

Comment: Sure, but you're pushing your luck for the reader to get it on first try.

Comment: Integrated (defining) relative clauses can be stacked, but the clauses in your examples are not relatives; rather, they are past-participial clauses. Why would you want to concoct such weird constructions?

Comment: 3a: *The door closed by the janitor [**which** was] expected to be **opened** by the principal.* 3b: *The door closed by the janitor [**who** was] expected to be **sacked** by the principal.*

Comment: Commas can help. _This is the door originally expected to be opened by the principal, but just recently locked by the janitor by mistake_.

Comment: First you need to come up with an end to your sentence. e.g.: *The door [that was] closed by the janitor [that was] expected to be opened by the principal was damaged.* Then you can see the garden path problem when you try to reduce the second relative clause: *The door [that was] closed by the janitor expected to be opened by the principal was damaged.* We are led to believe that the door was doing the expecting, right before the whole sentence devolves.

Comment: Related: [Is 'Women men girls love meet die' a valid sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235017/is-women-men-girls-love-meet-die-a-valid-sentence/235174#235174) (nested relatives) 'This is the lady who bought the car that had the fancy grille that I told you about' is perhaps still within the realm of the unremarkable.

Answer (score 0):

The Nursery rhyme "The House that Jack Built" consists of increasing relative clauses.

> This is the house that Jack built.

The number of relative clauses then increase and the rhyme ends with 16 relative clauses:

> This is the farmer that sowed the corn,
>
> That kept the cock that crowed in the morn.
>
> That waked the priest [who was] all shaven and shorn,
>
> That married the man [who was] all tattered and torn,
>
> That kissed the maiden [who was] all forlorn,
>
> That milked the cow with the crumpled horn,
>
> That tossed the dog,
>
> That worried the cat,
>
> That killed the rat,
>
> That ate the malt
>
> That lay in the house that Jack built.

The commas are to help breathing... The relative clauses are theoretically limitless.

Comment: Note that OP's example uses past-participle clauses.

Comment: Lose the [who was] and you have a few PP clauses, and the model for converting them all.

Comment: Haven't you seen the earlier debate over whether whiz-deletion is a valid concept? And a main proponent, John Lawler, [adds the caveat](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121615/passive-vs-active-or-omission-of-which-is/121619#121619) 'Whiz-Deletion is the source of virtually all post-nominal adjectival phrases, like ...'